# Snackbar(text="Message") in KivyMD does NOT contain the "text" property, why is this?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivymd

I am trying to create a Snackbar message and everything I have searched in the docs and online shows to use the "text" property. It simply does not exist.

I tried to use a workaround by creating a button in the Snackbar that contains text but this didn't show either.

Note: I am using KivyMD version 1.2.0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pip to specifically install the latest version that contains the docs (KivyMD 1.1.1 instead of 1.2.0 which I was using the whole time) and this fixed the issue!

```
pip install kivymd==1.1.1
```